# Using time but ignoring date in Excel

Tags: excel, date, time

Thanks for reading.

I have a sheet that records events in dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM am/pm format (eg 01/01/2013 06:51 am).  This information is in located in M2:M14053.

I need to work out how many events were logged per hour, the date they happened is irrelevant.  (eg how many events were logged between 8am and 9am)

I have control cell where I entered the hours from 00:00 to 23:00 in L14055 to L14078.

When I use the formula in cell M14055 "=SUMPRODUCT(($M$2:$M$14053>L14055) * ($M$2:$M$14053 < L14056))" it returns 0.

It’s doing this because the events are logged with the date and the control cells are only times.  The events are being logged in the six month period of 01/01/13 to 01/07/13 and I have over 14000 events.

I need to be able to calculate the amount of events that happen per hour as a total and ignore the dates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you enter just numbers 0 to 23 in L14055:L14078 and then use HOUR function like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((HOUR($M$2:$M$14053)=L14055)+0)`